# Conversion of a list to map with key as Account and map as account's corresponding contacts from a list of accounts

Tags: apex, list, map

I have a list accountList which contains corresponding contacts aswell. Now I am trying to make a map from that list with key as single account and corresponding associated contacts as value.

```
public class ListToMapConversion {
   public list<Account> accountList =new list<account>();
    public map<Account,contact> accmap=new map<Account,contact>();
    public void convert(){
        accountlist=[select id,name,(select lastName,phone,email from contacts) from account];

        for(Account a:accountlist){
            accmap.put(a,a.contacts);
        }

        system.debug(accmap);
    }


}
```

> 

Comment: So what's your problem exactly? Generally, using SObjects as keys in a Map is not a good practice due to performance issues and keys must be immutable. Use Account Id instead

Comment: getting an error saying that list has no rows. But when I execute the query in the query editor am getting records

Comment: That error couldn't occur here. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: not getting any records to display after its executed. no errors as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a.contacts` returns the `List<Contact>` so, variable declaration needs to be changed as follows:

```
public map<Account,List<contact>> accmap=new map<Account,List<contact>>();
```

And rest of the code will work fine.